# Understanding 'and' and equal to operators in R

Tags: r

In R, `TRUE && factor(FALSE)` gives an error but `TRUE && factor(FALSE) == FALSE` returns `TRUE`. When `TRUE && factor(FALSE)` cannot be computed then how does R compares it with `FALSE`?

Also `FALSE && factor(FALSE)` returns `FALSE` but `FALSE && factor(FALSE) == FALSE` returns `FALSE`, it should return `TRUE` because the left hand side expression evaluates to `FALSE`. I tried `FALSE && factor(FALSE) == TRUE` but that also returns `FALSE`. Can someone explain the above results?

Comment: `(FALSE && factor(FALSE)) == FALSE` vs. `FALSE && (factor(FALSE) == FALSE)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly look at the [operator precedence](https://www.datamentor.io/r-programming/precedence-associativity). As per the list `==` as highest precedence then `&&` so the `FALSE && factor(FALSE) == FALSE`returns `FALSE` as it first evaluates `==` and `&&`. If you want to execute `&&` first and then `==` then use the proper bracket:

```
(FALSE && factor(FALSE)) == FALSE
```

And it returns `TRUE`. If you execute:

`FALSE & factor(FALSE) == FALSE`

Then first it executes `factor(FALSE) == FALSE` which executes to `TRUE` and then `FALSE && TRUE` so finally you will get `FALSE`.